# clang error - library not found for DS.Store

Tags: java, gradle, clang, gluon

I have an evasive problem trying to follow this example: http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/:

After correcting `DekstopLogService` to `DesktopLogService` I made sure I could call platform specific implementation correctly.

I kept having problems with ios implementation which involves native Objective-C code. By building the `.a` library in a standard gradle project I could better understand the build script - thus I am manually moving the `libLog.a` into place. I had problems with that my implementation did not seem to get called - and I could not know wether or not it was due to a faulty library.

When trying to check wether or not `jni.h` had to be placed inside the `native` folder I got into this (clang) error: **library not found .../jniLibs/DS.Store** when building ios. I tried to rebuild the library but the problem persisted.

After adding `#include "IOSLogService"` to the top of my `Log.m`. The build suddenly worked and the Objective_C implementation functioned for the first time.

[image]

But when removing the line in `Log.m` it kept working. It also worked when I removed the whole native folder. I built a new `libLog.a` from another `Log.m` - where I made some edits. However the functionality of the old `Log.m` was still there when I made another successfull build. Then I got into the same error again - unable to build. This all happened yesterday - and I could **not** put it back into place and get it to work again. I tried replacing `libLog.a` with the original one that worked - but no.

Today - still having the same issue, I searched the error - and about DS.Store. I created a new empty folder `jniLibs` onto dekstop and placed the already existing `libLog.a` in it - then moving it into place into the Gluon project. Now it all worked again - and I have been able to build `libLog.a`s files from different sort of `Log.m` files - and I get the expected type of functionality each time ever since.

In short the error is about: Clang error when building to ios `failed link ... jniLibs/DS.Store`

---

This is the whole error message:

Linking 12299 classes (ios thumbv7 release)
103811 methods out of 103811 included in the executable
Building ios binary /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/SendingShit
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -o /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/SendingShit -arch armv7 -Wl,-filelist,/Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/objects0 -w -L /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.gluonhq/robovm-dist/2.3.1-ios11/edb33a25c7c3f6679b89cbcc3f15b267ccd3f15c/unpacked/robovm-2.3.1-ios11/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7 -ObjC -exported_symbols_list /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/exported_symbols -Wl,-no_implicit_dylibs -Wl,-dead_strip -fPIC -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -lrobovm-bc -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.gluonhq/robovm-dist/2.3.1-ios11/edb33a25c7c3f6679b89cbcc3f15b267ccd3f15c/unpacked/robovm-2.3.1-ios11/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7/librobovm-rt.a -lrobovm-core -lgc -lpthread -ldl -lm -lz -liconv -lsqlite3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework MediaPlayer -framework UserNotifications -framework AVKit -framework StoreKit -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libglass.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_font.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_iio.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_ios_webnode.a 
    -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_common.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_es2.a -l/Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/src/ios/jniLibs/.DS_Store -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/src/ios/jniLibs/libLog.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libRuntimeArgs.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libLifecycle.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libStatusBar.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libDisplay.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libBrowser.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libStorage.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libShare.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libCharm.a -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks
ld: library not found for -l/Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/src/ios/jniLibs/.DS_Store
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
:createIpa FAILED
:createIpa (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 1 mins 2.45 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':createIpa'.

  > org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Command '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -o /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/SendingShit -arch armv7 -Wl,-filelist,/Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/objects0 -w -L /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.gluonhq/robovm-dist/2.3.1-ios11/edb33a25c7c3f6679b89cbcc3f15b267ccd3f15c/unpacked/robovm-2.3.1-ios11/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7 -ObjC -exported_symbols_list /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/exported_symbols -Wl,-no_implicit_dylibs -Wl,-dead_strip -fPIC -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -lrobovm-bc -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.gluonhq/robovm-dist/2.3.1-ios11/edb33a25c7c3f6679b89cbcc3f15b267ccd3f15c/unpacked/robovm-2.3.1-ios11/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7/librobovm-rt.a -lrobovm-core -lgc -lpthread -ldl -lm -lz -liconv -lsqlite3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework MediaPlayer -framework UserNotifications -framework AVKit -framework StoreKit -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libglass.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_font.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_iio.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_ios_webnode.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_common.a -force_load /Users/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_es2.a -l/Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/src/ios/jniLibs/.DS_Store -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/src/ios/jniLibs/libLog.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libRuntimeArgs.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libLifecycle.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libStatusBar.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libDisplay.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libBrowser.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libStorage.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libShare.a -force_load /Users/home/NetBeansProjects/SendingShit/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/native/libCharm.a -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks' failed (Exit value: 1)

Comment: Please post the relevant code, it helps us a lot.

Comment: Post the native files and folders structure. Edit your question to reflect the new problem and clarify the old one was solved.

Comment: You don't need to include `#include "IOSLogService"` in the Log.m file. The .DS.Store file shouldn't be added to the jniLibs folder as the jfxmobile plugin might copy all the content from that folder, but it is not a library obviously. It seems everything is sorted out and you don't have a question after all?

Comment: I will let this question stand a couple of days. In case I come into the problem again. Otherwise it can be closed and I will repost the issue more clearly if I would come into it again in the future. It was never clear how it happened or how it was solved (2 times). I suspect there might be a temp folders somewhere - not getting cleared properly when using a new `libLog.a` and it can have been due to Xcode.

Comment: I have never seen or moved any .DS.Store file - the ios task simply complained of it

Comment: It occured again - and I could only solve it by creating new empty jniLibs folder on desktop, put in `libLog.a` and move it into the place

Comment: Hard to track this question. Anyway you said that you've created a different gradle project to build `libLog.a`, and when you do that you copy the result to your current project. This is somehow when the .DS file appears. You can see if the file is there with `ls -a` on a terminal. I'd suggest using the `installNativeTask` from the Go Native sample.